# Access Object Value

Tags: php, xml, object, simplexml

I am trying to pull out a value from inside a larger object. The main object from an xml file via SimpleXML.

When I `var_dump($data->extensions->runTime);` this section of the object I get:

```
object(SimpleXMLElement)#21 (1) {
  [0]=>
  string(8) "2852.462"
}
```

How can I access that 2852.462??

I have tried everything I can think of, via array [0], even with a foreach statement. I can't figure out how to access only the value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cast it to string:

```
$value = (string)$data->extensions->runTime[0];
```

Or better to float:

```
$value = (float)$data->extensions->runTime[0];
```

Comment: It worked. Thank you. The float example needs a capital T in 'runTime' but it worked.

Comment: @ATLChris Sry for the typo. Fixed it.